# How to send an integer through a socket?

Tags: c

I am trying to send an integer through a socket. I am using this code to do so; however, my C code will not compile. The compiler complains that myInt has not been declared.

```
int tmp = htonl(myInt);
write(socket, &tmp, sizeof(tmp));
```

How do I declare myInt? Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't this be titled, "How to I declare an integer?" What does the problem have to do with sockets?

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure that it was properly declared in your program ?

Try like this:

```
int myInt = something;    
int tmp = htonl((uint32_t)myInt);
write(socket, &tmp, sizeof(tmp));
```

Comment: Don't call `htonl` on data you plan to send through a socket.

Comment: @zneak: Could you elaborate? Normally that's *exactly* what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah, WTF? That's exactly what it's for.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: Sending raw data over a network is always a bad idea. It should always contained in way that the integrity and validity can be checked.

Comment: @Greg, @Andrew You need to call `htonl` on data you pass to __parametrize__ the network communication because your network card wants it in a specific byte order. For instance, you need it for ports and raw IP addresses. The data you send, on the other hand, is agnostic to endianness and will be received as is by the other end point. By calling `htonl` on the data you plan to __send__ (by opposition to the data you plan to parametrize the socket with), you only add confusion to your data protocol because the other endpoint then has to call `ntohl` on it to use it. It's just a spurious step.

Comment: @Greg Hwegill, @Andrew Medio In other words, it's useful for the fields in `sockaddr_in` that you pass to `bind`, `connect` and the like, but it's more of a nuisance for `write`, `send` and the like. Besides, there is no guarantee you'll be able to use it for all kinds of data. For instance, a string doesn't have a byte order, and as such you won't be able to call `htonl` on it before sending it.

Comment: @zneak - pssst, not all machines are x86. Your "spurious step" is how you ensure byte ordering. A big endian machine's `ntohl` won't alter the byte ordering since that's the order it *needs*

Comment: @zneak - as for your last comment, I really suggest you look at how binary protocols work. This isn't to be rude, you just kinda don't quite understand.

Comment: @Brian Roach I agree that byte order is important, but using `htonl` doesn't look like a good solution for it. These built-ins were made for networking and contain logic for 16 and 32 bit integers. There's no equivalent for, say, 64 bit integers or floating-point IEEE real numbers. I'm pretty sure you're better off with your own routines to switch whole structures; or simply declaring that your network protocol is little-endian, since this is a completely arbitrary choice.

Comment: @Brian Roach I did look at binary protocols and this is what I understood. Please enlighten me and tell me what I just kinda don't quite understand. It must be easy to point out if I'm so obviously wrong.

Comment: @zneak - `man endian` - there's been 64bit versions for a while now, and they are included in glibc.

Comment: @Brian The 64 bits functions you mention are [an extension to the XPG standard](http://opensolaris.org/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=67154). I can testify that at least Mac OS X doesn't implement them as of version 10.6.7.

Comment: @Kyle Hwang how about checking the most helpful anwser as `accepted`.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to just spend some time learning basic C before tackling the sockets library.

You need to declare myInt as a variable of type integer as follows:

```
  int myInt;
```

This introduces the compiler to an identifier called "myInt" whose type is int. The compiler can then make decisions as to whether you're doing legal things with myInt based on its type.

Its almost always a good idea to also give the variable an initial value:

```
  int myInt = 0;
```

Answer (score -2):

One simple solution is typecase the integer to char and send 4bytes of the char buffer

int myInt
char * ptr = &myInt;
write(socket, ptr, sizeof(int));

at the recieving end read the 4bytes.. 
u wont have any problem with the endianess.

Comment: You certainly will have endian-ness problems if the two hosts are of different endian-ness.

Comment: I think what you meant was to convert the integer to a textual representation (Such as you would see in XML or JSON). The problem is what you just posted ... doesn't do that. You'd need to use `sprintf()` for example to do the conversion.

Answer (score -2):

Convert everything to `char`, you won't have to worry about endianness because a `char` is a byte, read it byte for byte instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack.  When answering a question, it is best to either answer the question, or explain why another approach is better.

Comment: Doing that will ensure the receiving end has no idea how to read it. One should always use network-order when dealing with sockets.

Comment: Be sure to check to questions that are not principally answerable because of malformed assumptions.